# SAS: build linear regression model

Tags: sas, glm, proc, anova

I need to do build a simple regression model around the productivity of various land units in SAS but I am fairly new to it. I have the following parameters:

Prodbanana / ELEVATION / SLOPE / SOILTYPE

The productivity vaules of banana are in kg/ha; The elevation and slope parameters are already classified (6 classes) as well as SOILTYPE (6 classes)

The model should be: Productivity = x1* ELEVATION + x2*SLOPE + x3*SOILTYPE

I tried so far:

> proc glm data=Work.Banana2;
>
> class ELEVATION SLOPE SOILTYPE;
>
> model Prodbanana = ELEVATION + SLOPE + SOILTYPE;
>
> run;

But it returns the following error:`

> 45   proc glm data=Work.Banana2;
>
> 46   class ELEVATION SLOPE SOILTYPE;
>
> 47   model Prodbanana = ELEVATION + SLOPE + SOILTYPE;
>
> ```
>                              -
>
>                              22
>
>                                -----
>
>                                202
> ```
>
> NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
>
> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, (, *, -, /, @,
>                *CHARACTER*, *CHAR*, *NUMERIC*, |.
>
> ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
>
> 48   run;`

Any suggestions?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The addition operator is unnecessary. You can find a quick guide to model specification syntax
[here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect027.htm). Works across SAS regression procedures.